# How to get user media at Instagram with Instasharp

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, instagram

I´m using Instasharp to get user feed. It is working OK. But what need is the pictures a user post, the user media.

To retrieve the user feed I use:

```
var result = users.Feed("self");
```

I have been trying Recent but It is throwing and  error:

```
                authInfo.Access_Token = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["instagramAccessToken"];

            var users = new InstaSharp.Endpoints.Users.Authenticated(config, authInfo);
            var result = users.Feed("self");
```

Error: NullReferenceException. Object reference is not defined for an instance of the object

I´ve been trying to find an answer on how to do this with Instasharp, but with no success. 
Do any of you have this answer or a good link showing how to do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You mention an error, what is the error when you call `users.Recent()`?

Comment: Tnx. It is NullReferenceException. Object reference is not defined for an instance of the object.

Comment: That would lead me to believe that `users` is null. Can you post your code of how you're getting `users` set?

Comment: Sure, but users is not null, I see it filled in the debug. Here is the code: 
                authInfo.Access_Token = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["instagramAccessToken"];
            
                var users = new InstaSharp.Endpoints.Users.Authenticated(config, authInfo);
                var result = users.Feed("self");

Comment: I have the same exact problem. I think maybe its a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave up due my deadline, so I had to consume the JSON.

Get the JSON

```
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/xxxxxx/media/recent?access_token=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["instagramAccessToken"]);
        request.Method = "GET";
        String json = String.Empty;
        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            json = reader.ReadToEnd();
            reader.Close();
            dataStream.Close();
        }
```

Read it and insert in a database, using Linq to SQL:

```
            dynamic dyn = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
        foreach (var data in dyn.data)
        {
            RES_PostInstagram reg = new RES_PostInstagram();
            reg.filter = data.filter;
            reg.idPost = data.id;
            reg.image = data.images.standard_resolution.url;
            reg.link = data.link;
            reg.publicar = true;
            reg.thumbnail = data.images.thumbnail.url;
            reg.type = data.type;
            reg.created_time = this.UnixTimeStampToDateTime((double)data.created_time);

            if (data.caption != null)
                reg.caption = data.caption.text;

            foreach (string tag in data.tags)
                reg.tags += tag + ", ";

            // se o post nao existir no banco inserir
            RES_PostInstagram existe = (from p in this.ctx.RES_PostInstagrams
                                            where p.idPost == reg.idPost
                                            select p).FirstOrDefault();
            if (existe == null)
            {
                this.ctx.RES_PostInstagrams.InsertOnSubmit(reg);
                this.ctx.SubmitChanges();
            }

        }
```

Convert Unix Timestamp to DateTime:

```
        public  DateTime UnixTimeStampToDateTime(double unixTimeStamp)
    {
        // Unix timestamp is seconds past epoch
        System.DateTime dtDateTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        dtDateTime = dtDateTime.AddSeconds(unixTimeStamp).ToLocalTime();
        return dtDateTime;
    }
```